# Read a video file outside webroot using php

Tags: php, moodle

I am using moodle 3.1+. I am trying to read a file outside the webroot using readfile function. The file is a video file but is saved without any extension. Now, when I exeute the script I am getting the error "video can't be played because file is corrupt".

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
readfile('../../../../moodledata/filedir/17/73/17735b4721faa7d59e1fd8a2300135a3f04c9ea6');
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to show the file using below code.

```
$fs = get_file_storage();
$file = $fs->get_file_by_hash(sha1($filepath));
send_stored_file($file, 0, 0);
```

where $filepath is dynamically generated as below

```
"/$context->id/mod_lesson/mediafile/0".$lesson->mediafile
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your goal, but I don't think it's a good idea to access the moodledata in that way. How do you handle permissions? And how you will handle the case that file gets deleted?

Why not serve it through moodle itself? I assume you want to offer the files as download? /ressource/view.php would be a good entry point. YOu can build your custom script based on the redirect which uses view.php to redirect to the specific repository.

```
$path = '/'.$context->id.'/mod_resource/content/'.$resource->revision.$file->get_filepath().$file->get_filename();
$fullurl = moodle_url::make_file_url('/pluginfile.php', $path, $displaytype == RESOURCELIB_DISPLAY_DOWNLOAD);
redirect($fullurl);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was able to find the solution, and it serves it through moodle itself.